# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'display_name' in django

Tags: python, django

I have an django project where there are some apps , and `models.py` for each app with some ForiegnKey Fields. like below. for example this is `Master_data` app and inside models :

```
class MaintenanceType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = True, blank = True)    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.display_name or self.name
```

`calculator app` model:

```
class FamilyGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=name_choices)
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    family_type = models.ForeignKey(FamilySituation,
                                    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                    null=True,
                                    blank=True)
    maintenance_type = models.ForeignKey(
        MaintenanceType,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        limit_choices_to={'name__in': ['Single', 'Couple']},
        null=True,
        blank=True)
```

so i have a property function in the `FamilyGroup` model :

```
@property
    def maintenance_type_rate(self):
        b = self.maintenance_type.display_name
        r = MaintenanceTypeRate.objects.filter(
            Q(rate__gte=0) & Q(maintenance_type__display_name=b))
        for d in r:
            return float(d.rate or 0)
```

im getting an error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'display_name'` the error occurs at the `property function`
traceback:

```
File "/home/abdallaoss/cra-calculator/calculator/models.py", line 301, in maintenance_type_rate
    b = self.maintenance_type.display_name or

Exception Type: AttributeError at /calculator/transaction/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'display_name'
```

I tried this :

```
@property
    def maintenance_type_rate(self):
        try:
            b = self.maintenance_type.display_name
        except AttributeError:
            b = "No display_name found!"
        r = MaintenanceTypeRate.objects.filter(
            Q(rate__gte=0) & Q(maintenance_type__display_name=b))
        for d in r:
            return float(d.rate or 0)
```

Comment: When is this error happening ?

Comment: this error happens when i forgot to add something in this field

Comment: Well then it's normal... if this foreign key field is empty then you can't access its attributes... you should handle this with `try... except...`.

Comment: I added  `Try .... except` code above, but still i have the issue occurs, can u check please?

Comment: You have to put the `r = ...` part inside the `try` and handle the exception in the except.